# Matplotlib — How to put stacked barplots into subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, stacked-chart

I'm trying to plot two stacked bar plots in the same figure in matplotlib. The below code isn't absolutely minimal because I'm getting the same error even if I call the same plot into two different subplots, but since there would be no reason to plot the same plot twice I'm including the `groups` column to make the situation more approachable.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'groups': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
   'type_one': [223.3, 17.2, 13.5, 2.4, 9.2, 43.3, 15.2, 23.5, 21.4, 98.2],
   'type_two': [419.6, 42.0, 24.6, 33.6, 21.8, 11.5, 12.4, 91.2, 41.3, 16.2]
})

plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))

plt.subplot(121)
df[df.groups=='A'].plot.bar(stacked=True)

plt.subplot(122)
df[df.groups=='B'].plot.bar(stacked=True)

plt.show()
```

When I run this in jupyter notebooks, I get two empty subplots (one beneath the other, so not in the same figure), and then the second of the two plots appears below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This happens no matter whether I set `stacked=` to `True` or `False`, so I'm guessing it has something to do with `.plot.bar()` that I can't find in the documentation. When I try the same thing with `plt.bar()` the plot is produced normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the axis created by `subplot` and pass to `bar`:

```
ax = plt.subplot(121)
df[df.groups=='A'].plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax)

ax = plt.subplot(122)
df[df.groups=='B'].plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]

**Note** You can simplify your code with `groupby`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(12,4))

for (k,d), ax in zip(df.groupby('groups'), axes.flat):
    d.plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax)
```